# What does numpy.cov actually do

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and to linear algebra and I have a question about covariance of a matrix.

I have a 21 by 2 matrix, where the first column represents the average score(from 0 to 10) of the video games released that year and second columns are years ranging from 1996 to 2016.

I was playing around with the data and I noticed that by doing np.cov(X)
I got a very interesting graph. I will list the graph below. It is my understanding that covariance shows the dependence among the variables in a dataset, but will it be correct to state that based on this covariance graph we can say that the average score of the games rises as the years rise ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The "covariance" tag you selected has to do with polymorphism, not statistical data. Removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation isn't meaningful. By default, for `np.cov(X)` each row of X represents a variable, with observations in the columns. Say, the first row might be rainfall in a year, another the average rating of video games, and another could be just the number of the year itself, like 2012. Then `C = np.cov(X)` will give you a 3 by 3 matrix C where each diagonal entries says how much variance is within that row, and off-diagonal entries say how correlated the different rows are. Namely, the coefficient of the correlation of row i and row j is `C[i,j]/sqrt(C[i,i]*C[j,j])`.

If your data looks like `X = [[7.5, 2010], [8.2, 2011], [8.1, 2013]]`, then `np.cov(X)` is meaningless, because 7.5 and 2010 are not two different observations of the same variable. Rather, 7.5, 8.2, and 8.1 are different observations of the same variable (game rating). What you should use is

```
C = np.cov(X, rowvar=False)
```

to tell Numpy that your variables are in columns. You will get a 2 by 2 matrix (because there are 2 variables), in my example

```
  [[ 0.14333333,  0.38333333],
   [ 0.38333333,  2.33333333]]
```

Since the off-diagonal term is positive, it is true that two variables are positively correlated. Specifically, the coefficient of correlation is `C[0,1]/np.sqrt(C[0,0]*C[1,1])` which is 0.66, indicating pretty strong correlation.